# find a function $f$ such that $\| f \|_p$ is finite if $p\in(1,2)$ and infinite for $p=1$ or $p\in[2,\infty]$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm stuck in this problem and really I would appreciate a hint, I'm looking a Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\|f \|_p=\infty$ if $p=1$ or $p\in[2,\infty]$ and $\|f \|_p<\infty$ if $p\in(1,2)$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: consider $$f(x) = \left\{ \matrix{ x^{-a}, & \text{ if } |x|<1 \hfill\cr x^{b}, & \text{ if } |x|\geq1. }\right.$$ for suitable $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $\|x^{-r} \chi_{(0,1)}(x)\|_1 = \infty$ if $r > 1$ and $\|x^{-r} \chi(1, \infty)(x)\|_1 = \infty$ if $r \in (0,1)$, you can use
$$f(x) = x^{-1/2} \chi_{(0,1)}(x) + x^{-1} \chi_{(1, \infty)}(x)$$

Comment: @Zerox Yes it is?